Videos sent by PHP does not play on Safari
class VideotestPage
{

    function __construct($params)
    {
        $videoFile = '../static/v/videotest.mp4';
        if (file_exists($videoFile)) {
            //Send the headers
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($videoFile).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($videoFile));

            //Send file
            readfile($videoFile);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "404 - $videoFile.";
        }
    }
}

I need to send the videofile this way. In most browsers it works fine, but not in Safari on iOS 12-13 (but it works great on iOS 15-17).
Safari (12-13) just shows me icon with crossed out play button. No info in console (i use one of the web services for manual testing).
The same videotest.mp4 file works great if access it by direct link (i.e. example.com/static/v/videotest.mp4) on the same Safari (12-13)!
So the problem is probably not in this file.

Checking browser console may show some details.

I’ve read reports about Safari not being happy about servers not supporting range requests, maybe give that a try?
